# Swift - How to check if a map annotation (pin) is inside an array?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift

I have an array to store annotations. The annotations are added to the array only if you select on it. Once added, how can I check if an annotation is already inside the array? I don't want to have any duplicates - if I select a pin that is already in the array, it should not get added again.

This is my code:

```
    var pins = [[String : Double]]()

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {


    if editAndDoneButtonText.title == "Edit" {

        println("Pin Selected")

        var latFromPin = view.annotation.coordinate.latitude
        var lonFromPin = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude

        var selectedCoordinatePoint = ["latitude": latFromPin, "longitude": lonFromPin]
        var pinCoordinatePoint = ["latitude": latFromPin, "longitude": lonFromPin]


        pins.append(selectedCoordinatePoint)

        mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: true)


    }

    // Remove pins from map by tapping on it
    if editAndDoneButtonText.title == "Done" {
        var annotationToRemove = view.annotation
        mapView.removeAnnotation(annotationToRemove)

        println("remove pin - didSelectAnnotationView")
    }


}
```

I read other answers here and tried them but to no success. This doesn't work because it allows for duplicates. If I select multiple pins on a map, they each get added multiple times to the array:

```
        if pins.isEmpty == true {
            pins.append(selectedCoordinatePoint)
        } else if pins.isEmpty == false {
            for pin in pins {
                if pin == selectedCoordinatePoint {
                    println("ALREADY INSIDE ARRAY")
                } else if pin != selectedCoordinatePoint {
                    pins.append(selectedCoordinatePoint)
                    println("ADDED TO ARRAY")
                }
            }
        }
```

I've tried using an extension as well:

```
extension Array {
func contains<T where T : Equatable>(obj: T) -> Bool {
    return self.filter({$0 as? T == obj}).count > 0
    }
}
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: Is the order of annotations important, or do you just want a collection of all of them where order doesn't matter?

Comment: "This doesn't work:" - in what way? compile error, runtime error, unwatned functionality?

Comment: @Tom Harrington Ultimately, I want to select a pin and move to another view controller and show images associated with that specific pin. I haven't tackled this problem yet. I'm just trying to figure out this one currently. So I'm not sure if the pins will have to be in order. I'm new -- any recommendations?

Comment: @luk2302 I get a lot of duplicates in the array. It works fine with one pin, but if I select multiple pins on the map, I start to get duplicates inside the array. (I updated my question)

Comment: I am trying to guide you in the right direction here - have you tried logging / printing what the values in the array are and what the value is that you are trying to determine wether to isnert or not?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes I have. This is how I was able to see if the same annotation was being added again to the array.

Comment: Is the order important to you?

Comment: @ezcoding please see my previous comment to Tom Harrington. I don't think order is important. I have limited experience though. If you can provide either way to solve this, that would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latitude and longitude values as key for a `Dictionary` like this:

```
var pins = [String: [String : Double]]()

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {

if editAndDoneButtonText.title == "Edit" {

    println("Pin Selected")

    var latFromPin = view.annotation.coordinate.latitude
    var lonFromPin = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude

    var selectedCoordinatePoint = ["latitude": latFromPin, "longitude": lonFromPin]
    var pinCoordinatePoint = ["latitude": latFromPin, "longitude": lonFromPin]

    // old pins.append(selectedCoordinatePoint)
    pins["\(latFromPin)_\(lonFromPin)"] = selectedCoordinatePoint

    mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: true)
}
```

Each key can only exist once.

So you could retrieve it later like this:

```
for key in pins.keys {
  let selectedCoordinatePoint = pins[key]!
  // go wild with it
}
```

I would advice you though, to create a simple `Struct` with a latitude and longitude attribute, rather than working with arrays of dictionaries like this. An example:

```
struct MySimpleCoordinate: Hashable {

  var hashValue: Int {
    get {
        return "\(latitude.hashValue),\(longitude.hashValue)".hashValue
    }
  }

  let latitude: Double
  let longitude: Double

  init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
  {
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
  }
}

// must be declared in the global scope! and not just in the class scope
func ==(lhs: MySimpleCoordinate, rhs: MySimpleCoordinate) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

Now lets update that delegate with the new code:

```
var pins = Set<MySimpleCoordinate>()

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {

  if editAndDoneButtonText.title == "Edit" {

  println("Pin Selected")

  var latFromPin = view.annotation.coordinate.latitude
  var lonFromPin = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude

  let mySimpleCoordinate = MySimpleCoordinate(latitude: latFromPin, longitude: lonFromPin)
  var pinCoordinatePoint = ["latitude": latFromPin, "longitude": lonFromPin]

  // old pins.append(selectedCoordinatePoint)
  // pins["\(latFromPin)_\(lonFromPin)"] = selectedCoordinatePoint

  // there will be no duplicates in a Set
  pins.insert(mySimpleCoordinate) 

  mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: true)
}
```

And to retrieve all values you could do it like this:

```
for coord in pins {
  println(coord.latitude)
  println(coord.longitude)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!! I'm sticking to the array for now since its easier for me to understand. I tried your code and there is an error for this line:    pins["\(latFromPin)_\(lonFromPin)"] = selectedCoordinatePoint    -------> Error states: "Cannot assign a value of type [String : CLLocationDegrees] to a value of type [([String: Double])]?" -----> I converted the CLLocationDegrees to a Double and this error still persists. Do you know why?

Comment: You haven't implemented my code correctly. You have: `pins["(latFromPin)_(lonFromPin)"] = selectedCoordinatePoint`

But instead you should have: `pins["\(latFromPin)_\(lonFromPin)"] = selectedCoordinatePoint`

That's called [String interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292)

Comment: If you want to improve at programming, you should try different approaches to get the best results ;)

Comment: Never-mind previous comment. I got it to work by using dictionary: var pins = [String: [String : Double]]( )   ------- thank you!!